# How to navigate in angular2 to new tab

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a parameter to provide to the router so that **router.navigate()** will open in a new tab/window in browser?

Comment: The router doesn't support that. Why don't you just call `window.open()`? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Comment: I want to open a router url, not a regular one... Navigate in a new window to whatever the router is configured to. Is that possible?

Comment: That won't work. A different tab is a different application.

Comment: you are using routing using `<a>` tag ? routerLink ?? or in `.ts` file using `router.navigate...` ?

Comment: router.navigate in this case

Comment: Purpose of router is to load only necessary parts and render them where <router-outlet> is. If you open it in a new tab, it will bootstrap whole app again anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Create routes just like instructed [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

Set up your `app-routing.module.ts` ( or just put it in `app.module.ts` ), place the `<router-link>` in your `app.component.html`.

Now, to open a new window from the main page, ( or whatever sub-routes you have created ) just call a function, handled in the main component, that will point to the url of the sub-component route that you setup for the new window.

## Example snippits:

**app-routing.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component'; // main window
import { JclInfoComponent } from './jcl-info/jcl-info.component'; // new window/tab

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainComponent }, // main route
    { path: 'openJcl', component: JclInfoComponent } // new window route
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot( appRoutes )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<router-outlet>
    <!-- Just showing you that you can put things inside this. -->
    <template ngbModalContainer></template> 
</router-outlet>
```

**main.component.html**

```html
<button (click)="testMe()">myLabel</button>
```

**main.component.ts**

```js
public testMe() {
    window.open( "openJcl" );
}
```

Comment: I'm finding that I can't manipulate DOM elements above the route that I am currently using with this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.router.navigate([]).then(result => {  window.open(`/example/test/${my_var}`, '_blank'); });
```

[Angular 2 Routing navigate run in new tab(Use Angular Router naviagte )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521494/angular-2-routing-navigate-run-in-new-tabuse-angular-router-naviagte/50521527#50521527)