# Angular 2 Routing navigate run in new tab(Use Angular Router naviagte )

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

How to open a new browser Tab , if using router.navigate .

```
this.router.navigate([]).then(result => { window.location.href = link; });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Routing run in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355830/angular-2-routing-run-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try this one.

```
this.router.navigate([]).then(result => {  window.open(link, '_blank'); });
```

Comment: Why not `window.open(link, '_blank');` Direclty ?

Comment: This changes the current page's link and opens the same page in new tab. Whereas I want to keep the current page's URL intact and router.navigate should open a new tab.

Comment: Without `_blank` it worked for me `this.router.navigate([]).then(result => {  window.open(link); }`

Answer (score 7):

currently i believe angular doesn't offer any method or service to do that so i've to use `window` object to open links in a new tab
`window.open(link, '_blank')`

Answer (score 4):

To navigate to a new tab, instead of calling navigate directly:

```
this.router.navigate(routerCommands, { queryParams });
```

Use **createUrlTree** and **serializeUrl**, so you can build your URL with the same parameters used in navigate() but without navigating the current tab (only the new one):

```
 const link = this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree(routerCommands, { queryParams }));
 window.open(link, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 2):

this will open in new tab :

```
 this._router.navigate([]).then(result => {  window.open( `/customer/edit/${customer_id_param}`, '_blank'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const reportUrl = this._router.createUrlTree(['/your-url/endpoint', 
{data:"Data to pass"}]).toString();
window.open(reportUrl, '_blank');
```

Try this

Answer (score -1):

```
window.open(window.location.href+"/yourRoute", '_blank');
```

Answer (score -2):

Esto deberia funcionar tambien en angular:

```
  abrirVentana() {
var URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
window.open(URL, '_blank');
```

}

Comment: You are calling external url using window.open(). The question is about opening the router link in a new tab.