# Angular routing not working when trying to open an URL with query parameters in it in a new tab

Tags: angular, typescript, url, routes, window.open

**What do I wanna do?**
I want to implement a button which opens a URL in a new Tab. The URL contains a query parameter consisting of numbers taken out of the "displayData" object.

**Description of the problem:**
I have a route which is defined like this in the app.routes.ts:

```
{
  path: 'displays/:displayIds',
  loadChildren: () => import('module').then(m => m.module),
  canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
  data: {
    expectedRole: 'ROLE_READ'
  }
}
```

Next, I've got a HTML-Button which is calling the following method:

```
  openInNewTab(e: Event): boolean {
    e.preventDefault();
    const qp = {displayIds: this.displayData.map(display => display.deviceID).join(',')};
    const urltree = this.router.createUrlTree(['#/displays'], {queryParams: qp} );
    this.router.navigate([]).then(result=> {
      window.open(unescape(decodeURIComponent( this.router.serializeUrl(urltree) )), '_blank');
    });
  }
```

When you log the resulting URL, you get the following string:

http://localhost:4200/#/displays?displayIds=14361,14510

Which is exactly the one I want. But now is where the problem comes into place: If I click the button to open the URL in a new Tab, the correct URL is displayed in the searchbar for about a second. After that, the site goes blank and the error "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'displays%3FdisplayIds%3D14361,14510'" appears. If I take the **exact same** URL mentioned above this paragraph and paste it in the **same** tab which was opened before, the routing is done successfully and the site is displayed correctly.

My question is, why does the site only load if I paste the URL manually in the already opened site and how do I change the behaviour so that the site is displayed correctly on opening it per the button?

**Edit:**
For anyone that seeks a solution to the problem, the following configuration solved it for me:

I configured the route in app.routes.ts like this:

```
  {
    path: 'displays',
    loadChildren: () => import('module').then(m => m.module),
    canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
    data: {
      expectedRole: 'ROLE_READ'
    }
  }
```

In the module which is referenced in "loadChildren" I added the following configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'displays/:Ids',
    component: DisplaysComponent
  }
];
```

Now, if I call the URL like this 'http://localhost:4200/#/displays/3737" it's resolved as wished and redirects me to the correct page. I hope I was able to help y'all!

Comment: Does this give any good insight? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521494/angular-2-routing-navigate-run-in-new-tabuse-angular-router-naviagte

Comment: @pertrai1 No it doesn't really help as it's kinda the same procedure i showed in the question, but thanks for trying

Comment: Ok. I have the same problem. It will be interesting to see what others offer. If I can find a solution I will share

Comment: Why do you need the `navigate`...`then` ? can't you just do `window.open...` directly? I just tried it locally and it worked for me.

Comment: @AviadP. Originally, I only had window.open too, but as soon as I added the params the URL would not be assembled correctly. Adding the ```navigate().then``` solved the problem for me.

Comment: @All
Why # is getting added after port number?

Comment: @MiteshShah I'm not 100% sure, but I think the part after the "#" indicates a place on the page which should be displayed. E.g: If you have a URL "localhost:4200/home/#/middle, it tries to go to the part on the page "home" which is associated whit the id "middle". Hope that helps.